# Determining the type and structure of the database for nested data without references

Tags: mongodb, data-structures

I have a task: to store user messages from 3 messengers in the database. It is also necessary to exclude the possibility of re-sending the same message.

Accordingly, constant requests to verify the existence of a similar message and add new messages are assumed. I was going to to use a nested structure like:

```
messenger_name:
    sender_id:
        recipient_id:
            message_hashes
```

It seems to me, that a document-oriented database like Mongo should be suitable for this. But I do not know how to correctly divide everything into levels.

If I make a collection for each messenger, with a file for each sender, then the files will quickly become large.

Perhaps you advise a more correct approach, or even a different storage system.

Answer (score 0):

I would make **3 different collections for 3 different messengers** (as message is assumed to be same if sent from same messenger again).

Inside each collection, each document will represent 1 sender of this messenger and will have structure like,

```
{
  senderId,
  [
   {
     receipentId1,
     [messageHash1,messageHash2...]
   },
   {
     receipentId2,
     [messageHash1,messageHash2...]
   }
}
```

Then I will create index on the given fields(for faster retrieval to check case of message already exist).

Number of documents in this collection will be not more than the number of users of the app.